# ansible network parser for snow port-channel summary , NXOS command

Tags: ansible

There are network parsers written by Ansible to process show command output properly.  Some of them they created are at

https://github.com/network-automation/ansible-network-parsers

I am looking for network-parser for the command and output like this. Let me know if you someone good at these can help. We need output with list of ports as written in the above GitHub commands. Thanks for your help. I tried few things. Getting lot of yaml errors.

```
sffc07ssw01# show port-channel summary 

Flags:  D - Down        P - Up in port-channel (members)
        I - Individual  H - Hot-standby (LACP only)
        s - Suspended   r - Module-removed
        S - Switched    R - Routed
        U - Up (port-channel)
        M - Not in use. Min-links not met
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Group Port-       Type     Protocol  Member Ports
      Channel
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10    Po10(SD)    Eth      NONE      --
11    Po11(SU)    Eth      LACP      Eth1/1(P)    Eth1/2(P)    
12    Po12(SU)    Eth      LACP      Eth1/3(P)    Eth1/4(P)    
100   Po100(SD)   Eth      NONE      --
121   Po121(SD)   Eth      NONE      --
122   Po122(SD)   Eth      NONE      --
123   Po123(SD)   Eth      NONE      --
125   Po125(SD)   Eth      NONE      --
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we don't have to write network parser for this. Someone can explain how network parser work, I would like to learn.

For nxos, When we use transport as cli, we receive the output above. But if we use transport as network_cli, then output will be already in dictionary format.

````
ok: [xyz.com] => {
    "pc_output": {
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": false, 
        "stdout": [
            {
                "TABLE_channel": {
                    "ROW_channel": [
                        {
                            "group": 10, 
                            "layer": "S", 
                            "port-channel": "port-channel10", 
                            "prtcl": "NONE", 
                            "status": "D", 
                            "type": "Eth"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "TABLE_member": {
                                "ROW_member": [
                                    {
                                        "port": "Ethernet1/1", 
                                        "port-status": "P"
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        "port": "Ethernet1/2", 
                                        "port-status": "P"

This is the way I processed it
```yml
item looks like this

interface_port_channel:
 - { interface: Ethernet 2/1, channel_group: 122, mode: active }
 - { interface: Ethernet 2/2, channel_group: 122, mode: active }

---
- name: Interface portchannel info
  debug: msg="args {{item}} "

- name: configure lacp trunk with the given interfaces
  nxos_config: 
    lines:
      - conf t
      - interface {{item.interface}}
      - channel-group {{item.channel_group}} mode {{item.mode}}
      - exit
    provider: "{{ nxos_provider}}"

- name: "Get Port-channel summary"
  nxos_command: commands="show port-channel summary" provider="{{nxos_provider_network_cli}}"
  register: pc_output

- name: "Printing the port channel output"
  debug: var=pc_output

- set_fact: channel_group_info="{{run_pc}}"
  with_items: "{{pc_output.stdout[0].TABLE_channel.ROW_channel}}"
  when: item.channel_group == run_pc.group
  loop_control: 
      loop_var: run_pc

- debug: var=channel_group_info

- assert:
    that:
        - channel_group_info is defined
        - channel_group_info.layer == 'S' 
        - channel_group_info.status == 'U' 
        - channel_group_info.prtcl == "LACP"
    success_msg: "Port is switched"
    fail_msg: "Please check channel_group_info above to make sure Status, protocol and type is correct"

- set_fact: ports_info="{{item}}"
  with_items: "{{channel_group_info.TABLE_member.ROW_member}}"
  when: item.port == ''.join(item.interface.split())

- debug: var=ports_info["port-status"]

- assert:
    that:
      - ports_info is defined 
      - ports_info["port-status"] == 'P'
````